# itertools.tee' object has no attribute '__getitem__' after upgraded to Django 1.7rc2

Tags: django

I have just installed django 1.7rc2.
When trying to run the development server with manage.py I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    'itertools.tee' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Full traceback at: https://dpaste.de/8JS9.

Django 1.7rc1 works perfectly well.

Comment: This should be reported to a Django bug tracker instead, as this sounds like a Django bug? (if RC1 worked - check changelog)

Comment: Added ticket at: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23119

Comment: Fixed in this commit: https://github.com/django/django/pull/2990